# Displaying data with JSON encapsulated data

Tags: sql, json, serialization

Hello all I have a series of rows in SQL like this one:

```
Id      labels
979392  [2065027,236757,1831024,2398859,2497110]
```

Now what I would like to convert this into multiple rows like this:

```
id      labels
979392  2065027
979392  2036757
979392  1831024
979392  2398859
979392  2497110
```

Any Ideas?

Regards.

Comment: Check this out : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks! I've actually used the above in order to deserialize the data with this code:   SELECT 
(
select top 1 StringValue from parseJSON(labels)
) from table ; my problem now is to get it into the format above. The query that i tested only provided me one label and I want all labels for the same Id